# How to play sound from cocos2d-xna personal folder

Tags: c#, android, xna, cocos2d-x-for-xna

How can I play a sound from the

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
```

folder?

I have tried:

```
string path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Sounds/Twing.mp3");
CCSimpleAudioEngine.SharedEngine.PlayEffect(path);
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you get an exception ?
i assume that the specified sound is loaded via the content pipleline, 
so you would need to add that to your content project.

So if you see ContentPipeline, ContentLoader or something in the stack trace, this may be the correct answer.

I dit not find a way to directly pass the audio.
With images that is possible.

Comment: Yep with images it is possible, but looking for a way with sounds too.
I download a zipfile with images and sounds and unzip them in previous directory. But from there on I`m stuck zith my sound.